# how to make my outlook add-in visible even when no mail is selected for preview

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I created an outlook add-in with a simple manifest. But it's only clickable when a mail is previewed. How can I change this?

I tried setting:
`<SupportsNoItemContext>true</SupportsNoItemContext>.`
in my tag:
`<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">`
but the manifest format is invalid.

I would like my add in to be visible like the "Read Aloud".

Can you help me please :)
tanks

Answer (score 0):

There are couple nuances you must be aware of:

First, support for this feature was introduced in `requirement set 1.13`. See [clients and platforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/outlook-api-requirement-sets#requirement-sets-supported-by-exchange-servers-and-outlook-clients) that support this requirement set.

Second, in Outlook on the web, add-ins that implement the `<SupportsNoItemContext>` manifest element don't activate when the `Reading Pane` is hidden or when a message isn't selected. This is because add-in commands in Outlook on the web don't appear on the ribbon. To activate an add-in from the `Message Read` surface, you must first select a message, then select the add-in command from the message action bar.

```
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
    <SupportsNoItemContext>true</SupportsNoItemContext>
</Action>
```

Read more about that in the [Activate your Outlook add-in without the Reading Pane enabled or a message selected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/contextless) article.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, I use the solution generated by yeoman. Is it in the "commands.js" file that I have to put the function? Here is what I put in the "commands.js" file:  

`function openNewTab() {
  window.open("https://google.com");}`

In my manifest i put this : 

`<Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>openNewTab</FunctionName>
</Action>`

and 

`<bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.js"/> </bt:Urls>`

Comment: I've pasted a sample markup where you could use the `SupportsNoItemContext` element.

Comment: hello Eugene,

If my DefaultMinVersion in <requirements> is set to "1.3" is that work ? because i use <SupportsSharedFolders> who need to have the version 1.3